# Generating numbers with certain probabilities visual basics vba

Tags: vba, random, probability

I have some probabilities of

26% 18% 26% 20% 10%

and I want to generate some numbers (randomly in a certain range) based on the probability groups.

I have done that previously with 2 probabilities of 80% and 20% like below:

```
If rnd*100 < 80 then Output = 2 
Else  output = 10
End if
```

But I am not sure how to do that with more than 2 probabilities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random number in [0,1]. Start adding the probabilities (0.26, 0.18 etc.) until the exceed the chosen number. As soon as that happens -- pick the corresponding number in the range.

The following function is passed two arrays (assumed to be of the same length). The first contains the range of items (which need not be numbers) to sample from and the second array is the corresponding probabilities:

```
Function RandItem(items As Variant, probs As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, sum As Double
    Dim spin As Double

    spin = Rnd()
    For i = LBound(probs) To UBound(probs)
        sum = sum + probs(i)
        If spin <= sum Then
            RandItem = items(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    'if you get here:
    RandItem = items(UBound(probs))
End Function
```

It can be tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Randomize
    Dim i As Long, v As Variant
    ReDim v(1 To 50)
    For i = 1 To 50
        v(i) = RandItem(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(0.26, 0.18, 0.26, 0.2, 0.1))
    Next i
    Debug.Print Join(v)
End Sub
```

With typical output:

```
2 4 2 1 1 4 3 4 2 3 2 4 5 1 1 3 3 4 3 3 3 4 4 2 4 4 1 2 3 1 2 3 5 2 3 4 5 2 3 2 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 4 3 2
```

Here is a bar chart which shows 1000 random choices (using the same 5 probabilities):

[image]

As you can see, it does a good job of matching the target probabilities.

Comment: Why " RandItem = items(UBound(probs))" needs to be after " Next i" ? Thanks,

Comment: @Zapata Just a safety. Theoretically the probabilities should add up to 1, in which case you would always return a value from within the for-loop. But -- due to round-off error the actual numbers might (say) add up to 0.999. If that were the case, then there would be a 1/1000 chance of going through the complete loop without returning a value. The code that you ask about treats such cases as belonging to the last number of the distribution. I could have avoided that line by replacing the condition `if spin <= sum` by the condition `if spin <= sum or i = UBound(probs)`.

Comment: OK great! My outputs are not as accurate as I wanted +- 5 % . Do you know how can I have more accurate results? Do you know if we can reach to 100% accuracy in terms of having categorized probabilities? (26% 18% 26% 20% 10%)

Comment: How close observed frequencies are to theoretical frequencies is a function of sample size. You are probably observing the sort of thing which probability theory say that you *should* observe (with random samples generated by the given distribution). If you want the observed frequencies to match the theoretical frequencies as much as possible, but with an element of randomness thrown in -- perhaps what you want is a random permutation? You could also use a hit-and-miss approach -- use the function in a while loop until you get acceptable tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very similar. Instead of writing a huge if-clause you can leverage the vba's switch case:

```
Select (rnd*100)
    Case 0 to 26:
        ' do prop 1
    Case 26 to 44:
        ' do prop 2
    Case 44 to 70:
        ' do prop 3
    Case 70 to 90:
        ' do prop 4
    Case 90 to 100:
        ' do prop 5
End Select
```

Comment: this gave me    0.263305322    0.156862745     0.277310924   0.201680672   0.100840336     should be over lap between groups or not? like case 2 might need to be changed to 27 to 45?

Comment: I guess this is a pretty good result. Remember you are generating random numbers. You will never hit your exact probability...

Answer (score 1):

you can exploit a nice propriety of `Median()` function like follows:

```
probs = Array(0.26, 0.18, 0.26, 0.2, 0.1)
vals = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

For i = 0 To UBound(probs) - 1
    If prob = WorksheetFunction.Median(prob, probSum, probSum + probs(i)) Then Exit For
    probSum = probSum + probs(i)
Next I
output = vals(i)
```

a full and (hopefully) optimized example of which could be the following

```
Sub main()
    Dim vals As Variant, probs As Variant, probsSum As Variant
    Dim genVals(1 To 50) As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    probs = Array(0.26, 0.18, 0.26, 0.2, 0.1)
    vals = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    probsSum = setSums(probs) '<~~ calculate the probs sum once for all!

    For i = 1 To 50
        Randomize'<~~ 'randomize' before picking a Rnd() if you need a different seed for each one
        genVals(i) = GetVals(Rnd(), probsSum, vals)
    Next i        
End Sub


Function GetVals(prob As Double, probsSum As Variant, vals As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(probsSum) - 1
        If prob = WorksheetFunction.Median(prob, probsSum(i), probsSum(i + 1)) Then Exit For
    Next i
    GetVals= vals(i)        
End Function


Function setSums(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim sumArr(0 To UBound(arr) + 1)

    sumArr(0) = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        sumArr(i + 1) = sumArr(i) + arr(i)
    Next i
    setSums = sumArr
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to pick a value randomly with a defined distribution:

```
Dim values(), probabilities()

' define the values and the cumultated probabilities for 26% 18% 26% 20% 10%
values = VBA.Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
probabilities = VBA.Array(0, 0.26, 0.44, 0.7, 0.9)

' generate one value
Debug.Print values(Application.Match(Rnd, probabilities) - 1)
```