# Probabilistic Random Selection from Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, random, probability

I'm new to VBA here. I have 2 lists, a list of price, and a list of the probabilities assigned to the price. I need to generate a list of 300 numbers based on the probability group. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I ripped a code off another post:

```
Function RandItem(items As Variant, probs As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, sum As Double
    Dim spin As Double

    spin = Rnd()
    For i = LBound(probs) To UBound(probs)
        sum = sum + probs(i)
        If spin <= sum Then
            RandItem = items(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    'if you get here:
    RandItem = items(UBound(probs))
End Function
```

And also

```
Sub test()
    Randomize
    Dim i As Long, v As Variant
    ReDim v(1 To 50)
    For i = 1 To 50
        v(i) = RandItem(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(0.26, 0.18, 0.26, 0.2, 0.1))
    Next i
    Debug.Print Join(v)
End Sub
```

to adapt to my code. However, the problem is that the price range grows, and the probability changes over time (due to historical weightage). So I tried to switch the:

```
RandItem(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(0.26, 0.18, 0.26, 0.2, 0.1))
```

to

```
Dim i As Long, v As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim arrayPrice As Variant
Dim arrayProPrice As Variant
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
arrayPrice = Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2
arrayProPrice = Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value2
ReDim v(1 To 300)
    For i = 1 To 300
        v(i) = RandItem(arrayPrice, arrayProPrice)
    Next i
    Debug.Print Join(v)
End Sub
```

and it returned:
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range. Anyone has any suggestions how to fix this so I can use array variables instead of listing out all the price ranges?

Credits:
[Generating numbers with certain probabilities visual basics vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356179/generating-numbers-with-certain-probabilities-visual-basics-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dynamic solution does not work because `arrayPrice` and `arrayProPrice` are not 1-dimensional arrays, as expected by `RandItem`, but are 2-dimensional. This is because Excel Ranges can in general have multiple rows *and* multiple columns, and so the `.Value2` and `.Value` methods return a matrix.

For instance, if in your Excel sheet you have A2=1, A3=2 and A4=3, then `arrayPrice` will be `Array(Array(1), Array(2), Array(3))`.

You will first have to flatten that matrix to a 1-dimensional array before calling `RandItem`. The same goes for `arrayProPrice`.

You could use an Excel function to facilitate that:

```
arrayPrice = Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A" & LastRow))
arrayProPrice = Application.Transpose(Range("B2:B" & LastRow))
```

Comment: I see, that is a great insight indeed! How do I go about this if I may ask further?